# WPF Converting from list of files to custom object - in Model or Viewmodel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF application that displays a list of files/folders to the user in a treeview and they select which ones they want to load for the app. The ViewModel stores the folders/files in a DirectoryItem class that is binded to the UI:

```
public class DirectoryItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public String DisplayName { get; set; }
    public String Fullpath { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<DirectoryItem> Children { get; set; }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

The way I'm handling it now, the Model is passed a root directory and returns a List of string with every file in/under the root directory. Then, the ViewModel has a BuildDirectoryItemCollection function that converts the list into the ObservableCollection of DirectoryItems.

This is my first WPF app so I want to make sure I'm following the MVVM pattern correctly. Am I correct in thinking that the conversion from the List to ObservableCollection should take place in the ViewModel? Should the Model even have knowledge of the DirectoryItem class?

And as a side note, I'm not convinced that passing in a List of filepaths and then rebuilding the folder structure from that List is a good way of building my ObservableCollection. I am open to suggestions on a better way to do this!

Thanks for your time.

Comment: ObservableCollection<> implements IEnumerable just like List<>? If yes then it's OK to use it in model

Comment: If this is the dto or domain model I would not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Can you expand on that? I'm not sure what you mean. If the user decides to choose a different root path and I have to build the list of files again, I want the UI to be notified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what your model actually is in this case, but since you are just creating `DirectoryItem` objects based on the structure of a folder on disk, you might as well do all this, i.e. build the `ObservableCollection<DirectoryItem>`, directly in the view model class.

So you could for example inject the view model class with the path of the root directory (a `string`) and create the `ObservableCollection<DirectoryItem>` that you bind to in the view directly in the constructor of the view model.

It seems unnecessary to first build a `List<string>` and then build an `ObservableCollection<DirectoryItem>` based on this list instead of building the `ObservableCollection<DirectoryItem>` immediately.

A method that creates a hierarchical collection based on a file path is perfectly fine to implement in the view model. Don't overcomplicate things :)